# Correct pronunciation of the word הרהורים in the Hamapil bracha

Tags: pronunciation, vowels-nekudot, hamapil

I have seen two different ways to pronounce the word הרהורים in the Hamapil bracha said before sleep.

One have the vowels like this: וְאַל יְבַהֲלוּנִי רַעְיוֹנַי וַחֲלוֹמוֹת רָעִים **וְהִרְהוּרִים** רָעִים
i.e. ve'hirhurim

The other way is like this: וְאַל יְבַהֲלוּנִי רַעֲיוֹנַי וַחֲלוֹמוֹת רָעִים **וְהַרְהוֹרִים** רָעִים i.e. ve'harhorim

My question is- which is the correct pronunciation (nikud) and why?

Answer (score 3):

The word הרהור (and its plural) are the verbal noun of the verb הרהר, meaning to think, or to ponder. הרהר is in the verb form פיעל, meaning it has two syllables - a chirik under the first (root) letter, and a segol under the second to last (root) letter. (In short, הרהר is pronounced hirher).

Verbal nouns of this verb form keep the chirik sound, and replace the segol with a  וּ. So הרהר=hirher, becomes הרהור=hirhur.

An example of this in tanach (since the word itself doesn't appear) is the word כפר (kiper-atoned) (see Vayikra 16:18) which becomes כיפור (kippur-atonement) (for example Vayikra 23:27).

Therefore it should be pronounced hirhurim.

['Harhur' would not be the verbal noun of any verbal form, there are too many to write here but you can find them all here, among other places: https://milimilim.co.il/%D7%A9%D7%9E%D7%95%D7%AA-%D7%94%D7%A4%D7%A2%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%94]

Another sign that it's pronounced 'hirhur' is the many places where mepharshim write the word as הירהור (which must be pronounced hirhur). For example, yerushalmi sh'vuos (1:6)

> העולה מכפרת על הירהור הלב
> the Olah [Korban] atones for thoughts of the heart

As well as a couple more talmudic sources, Jastrow, and many rishonim and Achronim. (The Smag, shulchan aruch, Targum yerushalmi, sfat emet, machzor vitry, another yerushalmi, and others, just from a quick search of sefaria).

After a look through the Cambridge Cairo Geniza manuscripts available online, I also managed to find one which used the spelling הירהורים:
https://cudl.lib.cam.ac.uk/view/MS-TS-NS-00121-00045/2

Another manuscript I saw spelled it הִרהוּרִים: https://www.loc.gov/resource/amedscd.2018757847/?sp=10&st=image&r=0.242,-0.161,0.731,1.099,0
(There were a few that spelled it הרהורים, but since they are not vowelized, it still makes it impossible to tell how they meant for it to be pronounced).

And even though in Daniel (4:2) it says

> וְהַרְהֹרִין֙ עַֽל־מִשְׁכְּבִ֔י

This seems to be a rare case, in addition to it being in aramaic. Almost all of the other sources that I saw were either spelled with a yud or vowelized with a chirik (at least by sefaria).

At the end of the day, both pronunciations seem to have at least some sources that support them. However, the manuscripts which use the hirhurim pronunciation , as well as the general rule of פיעל verbal nouns, in addition to the list of rishonim and Achronim who spell it הירהור in other places, makes והרהורים as 'v'hirhurim' more likely.

Comment: חֵ֥לֶם חֲזֵ֖ית וִֽידַחֲלִנַּ֑נִי וְהַרְהֹרִין֙ עַֽל־מִשְׁכְּבִ֔י וְחֶזְוֵ֥י רֵאשִׁ֖י יְבַהֲלֻנַּֽנִי

Comment: The Hebrew of the siddur is neither pure Biblical Hebrew nor pure Rabbinic Hebrew (nevermind that Rabbinic Hebrew covers a wide range), so arguments from Tanakh or Rabbinic spellings of הירהור don't settle the matter. Additionally, there are Biblical Hebrew words that don't "match a binyan" (ie. the mishkal is not obviously attributable to a binyan), and are very similar to הַרְהוֹר, like בַּקְבֻּק and חַרְחֻר, and ones with a first radical that otherwise have the same vowels, like פְּתַלְתֹּל. Note also the mishnaic גַּרְגֹרֶת.

Comment: @magicker72 , although it's true that the Hebrew of the siddur is not necessarily biblical or rabbinic Hebrew, we don't have access to many old siddurim, which makes other texts our best bet. Besides for the fact that this specific bracha is actually in the gemara (where incidentally sefaria, again, has it with a chirik). As for other similar sounding words, I don't recognise some of the words you mentioned, but the ones I do don't verbalise (at least in modern Hebrew), unlike הרהור

Comment: @Loani What do you mean? We have plenty of handwritten siddurim with nekudot! You didn't cite any of them.

Comment: @Loani All extant witness to Brachot 60b have הרהו׳ or הרהורים, with no yud.

Comment: @magicker72 , I saw that the gemara in  brachot had no yud, if that were proof it would make this question a pretty simple one. But it's not really that simple, because it can be spelled without a yud, but pronounced with a chirik

Comment: @DoubleAA I've edited my answer to address that passuk (though possibly not sufficiently)

Comment: @magicker72 after going through a list of literally hundreds of manuscripts from Cambridge and the British museum (and others), I found 2 manuscripts that either had nikkud or added a yud. Both were added into the answer